# How to fix "not defined", but it is defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, class, tkinter

I am coding something with python and I made a main class. I am working with tkinter.
In my class
class Main(tk.Tk):
I have multiple variables. There are two variables, which I defined. Underneath that, there is another variable, that runs the other two variables, I wrote above. But then it says, that those are not defined, but it is. The Error message: name 'bruteforceABC' is not defined

```py
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def bruteforceABC():
        for length in range(1, 3): # only do lengths of 1 + 2
            to_attempt = product(chars, repeat=length)
            for attempt in to_attempt:
                    print(''.join(attempt))

    def clear1():
        list = window.grid_slaves()
        for n in list:
            n.destroy()

    def clearforce():
        bruteforceABC()
        clear1()
```

I don't know, why it says, it is not defined. Because I've defined it. What can I do, that I don't get this error?
Thank you, for your help!

Comment: Please include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: It says _WHAT_ is not defined?

Comment: @BryanOakley did it.

Comment: @G.Anderson It says, that bruteforceABC and clear1 are not defined

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your current code appears to be missing at least two module imports and perhaps a driver program -- as well as the error message.

Comment: To be clear on naming, those aren't variables, those are functions. You haven't showed us how you are calling those functions, or where you create an object of the `Main` class

Comment: Those two names are *not* defined; what you've defined are instance methods, but you've tried to call them as generic (non-class) functions.  Since they're defined within a class, you have to invoke them with an instance of the class, or the class name.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this class design.

Comment: you can maybe try using self keyword which refer as class object, but this way you cannot call them as generic functions

Answer (score 1):

You have defined these functions as class methods but are calling them as generic ones. You should use `self.method()` to call them.

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    @staticmethod
    def bruteforceABC():
        for length in range(1, 3): # only do lengths of 1 + 2
            to_attempt = product(chars, repeat=length)
            for attempt in to_attempt:
                    print(''.join(attempt))

    @staticmethod
    def clear1():
        list = window.grid_slaves()
        for n in list:
            n.destroy()

    def clearforce(self):
        self.bruteforceABC()
        self.clear1()
```

Like this

Comment: Thank you. But I've got one more question to you. (I forgot to write that in the post sorry). In the same class I've got this: '''python'' if clearforce():
        time.sleep(5)
        tk.Label(window, text="clear1").grid(row=0)
    else:
        tk.Button(window, text='ABC-Attack', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
        column=1, 
        sticky=tk.W, 
        pady=4) ' ' ' It says, that "clear force" misses a self. If I write "clearforce(self), it says, it's not defined. Do you know, what I am doing wrong here? Thanks again.

Comment: You should use `self.clearforce()`. This does 2 things, it tells python that you are using a function defined on the class, and also passes the instance of the class  you are using as the first argument. 
It is the equivalent of doing 
`MyClass.function_name(self)`.

Comment: Are you calling this from within the class? Or from somewhere else? If the latter, try calling an instance of the class instead, so do `Main().clearforce()`.